# Get information from 2 parent tables referenced in 1 child table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, many-to-many, relational-database

Imagine these tables

Persons

```
id name
1  John
2  Jane
3  Joe
4  Jill
```

Things

```
id name
1  Apple
2  Banana
3  Carrot
```

Has

```
pid tid
1    1
1    2
2    3
```

Where `Has` is the many-to-many relationship between `Person`s and `Thing`s. How would I be able to get the original parent table information for all `Person`s and `Thing`s that have a relationship?

Basically something like:

```
pname tname
John  Apple
John  Banana
Jane  Carrot
```

This sounds like one of the most fundamental SQL things so I know this is a basic question, but I haven't been able to word it properly so I haven't been able to find answers while searching.

The following is the query I tried. I know this would just be the first step, since it gets the `Person`s involved, but not sure how to get `Things` as well

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    person p 
    INNER JOIN has h 
    ON p.id = h.pid;
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  and `JOIN` again.  Can you show the query that you tried?

Comment: Edited to add what I have so far. That gets all the ```Person```s that have a Has relationship. I see what you mean by having to join again, but I'm not sure what exactly. Would it be ```JOIN```ing ```Thing``` with that intermediate query on ```thing.id = h.id```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you continue:

```
SELECT . . .   -- the columns you want
FROM person p INNER JOIN
     has h 
     ON p.id = h.pid INNER JOIN
     thing t
     ON t.id = h.tid;
```